# xslt transformation for JSON response in wso2 API manager 1.9

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a sample backend response json in this format:
 I want to extract the comma separated values from the RESPONSEs and RESPONSE_ORDER tag, such that I can distinctly set them in my output JSON. Essentially, my output should be some what like this using xslt transformation.
Using xslt mediator I want to transform it as below:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [      
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "20",
        "QUESTION_ID": "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "xssdsdd",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"        
      }, 
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "21",
        "QUESTION_ID": "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "abc",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes,No",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1,2"       
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Sample output after transformation

```
{
    "results": [      
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "20",
        "QUESTION_ID": "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "xssdsdd",
        Response&Order: [
            {
            "RESPONSE": "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"
            }
        ]               
      }, 
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "21",
        "QUESTION_ID": "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "abc",
        Response&Order: [
            {
            "RESPONSE": "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"
            },
            {
            "RESPONSE": "No",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "2"
            }
        ]             
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I split the values to generate this kind of output?